# I am facing an error in my ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is the error which i am facing:
"home.ts:40 Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 2"

I am fetching the data in list from the database using the API. line no 40 in home.ts is  err =>{
                  console.error("Error : "+err);
                } ,

home.ts:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams : NavParams, public http:Http, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private httpProvider:HttpProvider) {
        this.user_id = this.navParams.get('user_id');
        this.distributor_id = this.navParams.get('distributor_id');
        this.getdata(this.user_id, this.distributor_id);  
      }
        getdata(user_id, distributor_id){
          this.httpProvider.getAllData(user_id, distributor_id).subscribe(
            result => {
              this.newsData=result.complaint;

              console.log("Success : "+this.newsData);
            },
            err =>{
              console.error("Error : "+err);
            } ,
            () => {
              console.log('getData completed');
            }
          );

        }
```

http.ts:

```
getAllData(user_id, distributor_id){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    let postParams ='&fse_id=' + user_id + '&distributor_id=' + distributor_id;
    console.log(postParams);
    return this.http.post("http://www.btedge.appexperts.net/Ionic_Webservices/type.php", JSON.stringify(postParams), options).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Your API returns malformed JSON which is why `res.json()` throws an error.

Comment: when I run my api on postman.. I am getting correct format
{
    "complaint": [
        {
            "trans_id": "15",
            "lead_name": "mohan",
            "type": "NEW",
            "lead_phoneno": "12134242",
            "lead_alternetno": "2121323",
            "lead_address": "jaipur",
            "plan": "prepaid",
            "status": "Active",
            "telecaller": "prashant",
            "user_name": "rahul kumar"
        },
       ]

Comment: Maybe it is just a copy paste mistake now but there is a comma (`,`) too much in there and a bracket (`}`) is missing.

Comment: actually the result was long, so i pasted one record of it
} is there in the end in my original solution

Comment: Can you please add the full response to your question, properly formatted. And log the `res` variable before you call `.json()` on it and add it to your question as well.

Comment: Copy/paste the result of your ajax request in a json validator (example: https://jsonlint.com/) and check if this is a valid one.

Comment: @Christian Benseler
 It showed me the result: "valid JSON"